# A diferença entre req.params e req.query

Tags: node.js

Estou com uma dúvida sobre parâmetros de url. É o seguinte, eu sei que tem como eu resgatar um parâmetro dessa forma `users/:id`, ai nisso eu resgato com o `req.params.id`, mas vi um vídeo que o cara utilizou esse modo, `req.query` e nesse `req.query` ele colocou dentro de uma variável, e todos os parâmetros que ele passou via url ele conseguiu resgatar.

A minha dúvida é: qual a diferença deles? E em qual contexto devo usá-los??

Answer (score 4):

Edgar, pelo que conheço, o params são os parâmetro da URL do seu endpoint, enquanto o query, são os parâmetro enviados após o interrogação(?).

Por exemplo, nessa URL, ficaria dessa forma:

*http://www.test.com/xpto/?xisto=1*

**params** : xpto

**query** : xisto=1

Comment: Se estiver usando express, essa documentação deles é bem legal:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente os parâmetros query são utilizado para consultas/filtro. 
Por exemplo vamos supor que a sua aplicação trabalhe com empresas e funcionários.

Poderíamos ter a seguinte rota:

GET /empresas/1/funcionarios ( retornaria todos os funcionários da empresa 1 )

GET /empresas/1/funcionarios?ativos=true ( retornaria todos os funcionários da empresa 1 que estão ativos )

Answer (score -3):

O params vem da Url quando ela tem dois pontos, normalmente é usado para IDs, para acessar um item especifico do seu banco, por exemplo:

No Backend, `http://www.meusite.com.br/users/:id`, assim você cria um endpoint para acessar um usuário em especifico baseado no seu id.

Então no front `http://www.meusite.com.br/users`, acessando o usuário de id = 1.

---

O query também pode vir da Url, após a '?', normalmente é utilizado para filtros em pesquisas no banco, por exemplo:

No Backend, `http://www.meusite.com.br/users` e cria os acessos `req.query.status`, `req.query.idade`, `req.query.outros`.

Então no front acessa o endpoint dessa maneira `http://www.meusite.com.br/users?status=ativos&idade=30`, filtrando pelos usuários que tem o status ativo e igual igual a 30, ou você pode tratar para que seja idades maiores que 30 ou menor, vai da logica feita no backend e não se esqueça de documentar para que fica de facil entendimento dos filtros que podem ser usados.